# Looking for A Gallery Running On Javascript and/or JQuery Like One Click To Many Showcase

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, image-gallery

To see the example please visit the web page: `spam`
and click one photo you will see many photos appearing. How can I make it using JS or JQuery or what else? I will use .NET for active server pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be something like this.

HTML:

```
<style>dd { display: none; }</style>
<dl>
    <dt>Click me for images</dt>
    <dd><img src=""></dd>
    <dd><img src=""></dd>
    <dd><img src=""></dd>
    <dt>Click me for images</dt>
    <dd><img src=""></dd>
    <dd><img src=""></dd>
    <dd><img src=""></dd>
</dl>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('dt').live('click', function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').toggle();
});
```